# Comparing 2 objects and searching for differences

Tags: javascript, recursion, javascript-objects, syncfusion

I have 2 objects (created with Syncfusion editor - Word) and I need to compare if something inside the document (text) has been changed and it's working at least 50% but I don't know how to fix it because it's not detecting all changes

[image: Demo Image 1]

[image: Demo Image 2]

sfdtNewest = https://gist.github.com/danielediazmx/1003399a82cd1b082c1de517f6836ba8
sfdtOlder = https://gist.github.com/danielediazmx/ff625d79867eea11dd29b28cc5b703de

```js
const diff = require('deep-diff');

export function DocumentDiffer(sfdtNewest: string, sfdtOlder: string): string {
  if (!sfdtNewest || !sfdtOlder) return JSON.stringify(sfdtNewest);

  const newest = JSON.parse(sfdtNewest);
  const older = JSON.parse(sfdtOlder);

  let newestSections = newest.sections;
  let olderSections = older.sections;
  newestSections.map((newestSection: any, indexSection: number) => {

    newestSection.blocks.map((block: any, indexBlock: number) => {
      let addedIndexes: number = 0;

      block.inlines.map((inline: any, indexInline: number) => {
        let finalIndex = indexInline + addedIndexes;

        const lineToCompare = newestSections[indexSection].blocks[indexBlock].inlines[finalIndex];

        // TODO: compare in older inlines
        const oldSectionExist: boolean = olderSections.length >= indexSection;
        const oldBlockExist: boolean = olderSections[indexSection].blocks.length >= indexBlock;
        const oldInlineExist: boolean = olderSections[indexSection].blocks[indexBlock].inlines.length >= finalIndex;
        const oldInlines: boolean = olderSections[indexSection].blocks[indexBlock].inlines[finalIndex] != undefined;
        if (oldSectionExist && oldBlockExist && oldInlineExist && oldInlines && lineToCompare) {

          const oldLine = olderSections[indexSection].blocks[indexBlock].inlines[finalIndex];
          const nextLine = newestSections[indexSection].blocks[indexBlock].inlines.length > finalIndex ? newestSections[indexSection].blocks[indexBlock].inlines[finalIndex + 1] : null;
          const next2ndLine = newestSections[indexSection].blocks[indexBlock].inlines.length > (finalIndex + 1) ? newestSections[indexSection].blocks[indexBlock].inlines[finalIndex + 2] : null;
          const nextLineInOld = olderSections[indexSection].blocks[indexBlock].inlines.length > finalIndex ? olderSections[indexSection].blocks[indexBlock].inlines[finalIndex + 1] : null;
          const changes = diff(oldLine, lineToCompare);

          if (nextLine && !nextLineInOld) {
            // text added at the end
            nextLine.characterFormat.fontColor = "#45b464"
            newestSections[indexSection].blocks[indexBlock].inlines[finalIndex + 1] = nextLine;
          } else {
            if (changes) {
              changes.map((change: any) => {
                if (change.kind == 'E') {

                  if (change.path[0] == 'text') {
                    if (change.lhs != " " && change.lhs != "") {
                      // removed
                      if (nextLine && nextLine.text == oldLine.text || (next2ndLine && next2ndLine.text == oldLine.text)) {
                        addedIndexes += (nextLine && nextLine.text == oldLine.text ? 1 : 2);
                      } else {
                        oldLine.characterFormat.fontColor = "#b44545"
                        oldLine.characterFormat.strikethrough = "SingleStrike"

                        const inlines = newestSections[indexSection].blocks[indexBlock].inlines;
                        const iinlines = [
                          ...inlines.slice(0, finalIndex),
                          oldLine,
                          ...inlines.slice(finalIndex)
                        ];
                        newestSections[indexSection].blocks[indexBlock].inlines = iinlines;
                      }
                    }
                    if (change.rhs != " " && change.rhs != "") {
                      // added
                      lineToCompare.characterFormat.fontColor = "#00fff6"
                    }
                  }
                }
              })
            }
          }

        } else {}
      });

    });
  });

  newest.sections = newestSections;
  return JSON.stringify(newest);
}
```

Comment: why are you using `.map` everywhere and throwing away the result? you should use `.forEach` - that aside, you say it works 50%, which 50% works?

Comment: You are not comparing JSON objects which is not a thing, you are comparing objects (POJOs, Plain Old JavaScript Objects)

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+diff+nested+objects+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor. Make 2 example object not bigger than 5000 chars each, remove all the require and export and instead use a [cdn](https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/deep-diff)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Our SFDT has a complex structure format, so it is not working properly when trying to compare based on SFDT. For example, the below-attached document contains the same formatted content, so I didn't find any difference in the UI level, but the document doesn't match the SFDT level.

UI level:

Testdocument1

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXp0B.png)

Testdocument2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHlrZ.png)

SFDT level:

Testdocument1
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4TvG.png)

Testdocument2
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbQY5.png)

And already we have a feature plan for Word document comparison. We have planned to include this feature in our volume 3 release, which is scheduled for September 15, and we will inform you once this feature is included.

Support for Word document comparison in WinForms | Feedback Portal (syncfusion.com)